# Flickering in Android while keyboard dismissal?

Tags: android, performance, android-layout

[image]I am having issue with Android Tablet. 
I have created a runtime views as shown in Attachment(tab_before_error.png), when user clicks on Edittext then keyboard appears, after typing something I am making some operations in aftertextchanged callback. When I dismiss the Keyboard, there is Flickering as shown in attachment(tab_error.png).
 What's the issue, why the system not able to render the UI immediately once the keyboard dismissal.

Answer (score 3):

try to put the following line in ur activity tag in manifest..

```
              android:windowSoftInputMode="stateHidden|adjustNothing"
```